# Wordpress custom shortcode -> don't display if no parameter

Tags: php, wordpress, function, shortcode

A simple wordpress shortcode function gets the querystring key => value pair from the URL and outputs the value onto the page where the shortcode is placed. I set the parameter in the shortcode to determine which key to call e.g. [urlparam param="username"].

Unfortunately, if there is no querystring or if the querystring key is not present then the raw shortcode displays on the page rather than rendering any result or displaying nothing. 
How would I edit the shortcode function so that nothing displays if there is no querystring or if the key being looked for is not there?

```
function urlparam_function( $atts ) {  
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'param' => 'param',
    ), $atts ) );
    return $_GET[$param];
}
add_shortcode('urlparam', 'urlparam_function');
```

Answer (score 1):

If the querystring key is not empty, return the querystring value.  Otherwise return `null`.

Returning `null` results in nothing being displayed.

```
function urlparam_function( $atts ) {  
    extract(
        shortcode_atts(
            array(
                'param' => 'param',
            ),
            $atts
        )
    );
    return !empty($_GET[$param]) ? $_GET[$param] : null
}
add_shortcode('urlparam', 'urlparam_function');
```

Comment: Can you add a little explanation to what this is doing?

Comment: answer is updated now. check it again. in this code if the querystring key is not empty it returns the querystring value otherwise it returns null. returning null value from shortcode displaying nothing.

Answer (score 0):

remove  `$_GET` use only `$param` like below:

```
function urlparam_function( $atts ) {  
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'param' => 'param',
    ), $atts ) );
    return $param;
}
add_shortcode('urlparam', 'urlparam_function');
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't appear to make any difference. Here is where the original solution came from: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/245635/90668